# When do I really need InamingContainer Interface?

Tags: asp.net

I read in MSDN InamingContainer is a marker interface for creating unique name. When is it really necessary ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Frankly, it's required when your control has a child with an id. Whereas you can use multiple instances of your control on a single page, you have to mark your control with `INamingContainer` interface. This is the most senario for `CompositeControls`, thus it has derived `INamingContainer` by default.

Answer (score 2):

From [INamingContainer Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx)

> Any control that implements this
>   interface creates a new namespace in
>   which all child control ID attributes
>   are guaranteed to be unique within an
>   entire application. The marker
>   provided by this interface allows
>   unique naming of the dynamically
>   generated server control instances
>   within the Web server controls that
>   support data binding. **These controls
>   include the Repeater, DataGrid,
>   DataList, CheckBoxList,
>   ChangePassword, LoginView, Menu,
>   SiteMapNodeItem, and RadioButtonList
>   controls.**
>
> When you develop templated controls,
>   you should implement this interface to
>   avoid naming conflicts on a page.

Comment: If there is no databinding this isn't necessary then ?

Answer (score 0):

**very simple explanation about Inaming container interface**

http://www.robertsindall.co.uk/blog/2010/09/27/using-inamingcontainer-in-controls/#comment-95498